# vb2010 oledb select where select result

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I have a small issue dealing with oledb.
I have two excel tables:
one includes systems and responsible persons

```
    [person1|system1]
    [person1|system2]
    [person1|system3]
    [person2|system4]
    [person2|system5]
    ...
```

and another information about the systems

```
    [system1|location|weight|height]
    [system2|location|weight|height]
    ...
```

Now I want to be able to select a person and write the system information (for the systems of this person) to a datagridview

BY THE WAY: I can not change the tables as I get them from somewhere else.

My code so far:

```
    Using cn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With _
            { _
                .DataSource = "reports\PM.xlsx", _
                .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" _
            }
        Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0;")
        cn.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString

        cn.Open()

        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT F2 AS system FROM [table1$] WHERE F1 ='" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem & "'"
            Dim dr As System.Data.IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

            dtSheet1.Load(dr)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dtSheet1
        End Using
    End Using
```

Thatworks perfect so far, I recieve all system names in the datagridview but I have no clue how to select from the other table with the results from the first.
I need something like

```
     SELECT F2 AS location, F3 AS weight, F4 AS hight FROM [table2$] WHERE F1 =ONE OF THE RESULTS FROM THE QUERY ABOVE'"
```

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Are you asking how you can join the two tables so you can get all the system information for the ComboBox2.SelectedItem? Or are you asking how to get system information based on a selected person record?

Comment: Sorry my English isn't that good. In the end you should be able to select a person and the datagridview should show all systems with information from that person.

Comment: So what is the specific question? How to put the persons in a grid? How to get the selected person from the grid? Or, how to select data in the system information table based on a person?

Comment: How to select system information based on the systems I received as a result for the person. I ask for systems from Steve (example) and recieve 10 systems. But how can I select the system information for all 10 systems now?? Thanks

Comment: You want to join your data then: SELECT t2.F2 AS location, t2.F3 AS weight, t2.F4 AS hight FROM [table2$] as t2 JOIN [table1$] as t1 ON t2.f1 = t1.f1 WHERE t1.F1 ='" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem & "'"

Comment: Cool, that's it! Thanks Steve, you're a Star!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the data from both tables using your original query as the criteria:

```
SELECT t2.F2 AS location, t2.F3 AS weight, t2.F4 AS hight 
FROM [table2$] as t2 
  JOIN [table1$] as t1 
    ON t2.f1 = t1.f1 
WHERE t1.F1 ='" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem & "'"
```